# C# Dataset equivalent in java which can handle multiple data tables

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Need to migrate some data access function from vb.net to java.
Those vb function will call stored procedure which results multiple datatable.
In vb.net it's is handled using dataset.
Will access table by

```
dataset.table(0)
```

**Vb.net code**
Like:

```
Dataset ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connection && procedure details).
DataTable dt1 = ds.Table(0)
DataTable dt2 = ds.Table(1)
```

Now need any equivalent in java 8 to multiple tables from stored procedures

Have seen arround people saying about resultset , can resultset hold multiple tables from sp ??

If yes let me know how to use that.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent of `DataSet` or `DataTable` in JDBC.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I am not searching for equivalent, I am seeking for a solution for my migration. need a solution to handle multiple tables returned by Stored procedure